# Improvisation and Jamming - the Similarities and Differences

Tags: improvisation, jamming

I've been discussing with musos what similarities and differences there are between improvising and jamming. There seems to be a lot of vagueness here.

Some say that improvisation is one player making up melodies over established chord sequences, others that it's really confined to jazz (what about Liszt, et al !?) while jamming is starting from basically nothing, and each player adding their own part to the ensuing jigsaw.

So is it a case of all poodles are dogs, but not all dogs are poodles, in a way - or are there actually defined differences? There are certainly similarities, but could one finish playing in an ensemble situation, and say 'that was a good improv', or 'that was a good jam' with any exactitude? And would it be fair to say one (or both) are applicable to any particular genres? or definitely not, as the case may be? Dictionary definitions are also mixed and vague on the issue.

Comment: Both terms have unclear definitions but there's almost certainly a lot of overlap. Since the whole question depends on individual definitions of the terms: VTC as opinion-based. This was also discussed on meta.

Comment: @PiedPiper - I appreciate and know it was discussed on meta, but with no particular outcome, so I felt an open question might elicit something more lucid. There are undoubtedly folk out there who can proffer their take on the words - does that then mean it's subjective?

Comment: Did you preface this question by saying it’s subjective and you know it or am I misreading the first paragraph?

Comment: @ToddWilcox - I meant there seems to be several different explanations to the terms - I'm trying to get some consensus to their exact meanings, which may, as so many terms do, mean different things on each side of the Atlantic, for example. Trying my utmost to avoid the dreaded subjectivity!

Comment: “There seems to be several different explanations to the terms”. Yes. That is also one way to define “subjective”.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - I'm not looking particularly for opinions, but a better understanding of the terms - for this site as well as for me. I'm hard pushed to define the two exactly, but feel there must be some sort of good definitions of the two, if indeed they're not synonymous, which may turn out to be, depending upon answers. What are your definitions of the two?

Comment: I think I'll vote to close, but I wouldn't call it a "subjective" question. Rather the issue is it's more about language than about practice. Since different groups use the words in different ways, the only true objective answer is to document the ways that different groups use them. And that to me seems more about semantics than about the actual jamming or improv itself.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's essentially a survey of language-differences across music cultures rather than about practice. Similar words are used for different practices, and similar practices are labeled with different words. While this is of musicological interest, such a survey is perhaps too broad for a single question.

Comment: you could argue semantics but it's quite simply a matter of perspective, but all these perspectives see the same definition they just choose not to see it. improvise: make something up on the spot, jam: gel with music. give me one scenario where these two definitions don't fit

Comment: I may be repeating someone else’s answer. 
A jam or jamming refers to musicians improvising or playing unrehearsed music in the spur of the moment. 
Improvisation is widely understood as making up musical

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Jamming and improvisation share common ground but they are like music and noise. Music can be thought of as noise but it is not noise, it can be a sheet of paper with notes or performed within subconscious thought. Noise can be music but it is not music, it can be just noise (*although Frank Zappa would have probably argued this with some cosmic perception of reality*).

The **definition of improvisation is to perform something without preparation or without a plan**. What they are referring to there is strictly the act of improvising, what you play (irrespective of the accompaniment, such as backing tracks) is the improvisation.

This gets fuzzy when you consider that most *improvisation* (*with other musicians or backing music*) uses a prepared theme like a key (*eg. A minor*) or a beat (*eg. 4/4 120bpm*). This would be called a **jam session** but the *improvisation* is anything played during the jam that was made up on the spot.

**Jamming** is not a type of *improvisation*, to '*jam*' means to play with others, it's **an exercise that brings the musicians together** (*like sticking bread together with jam*). *Jamming* implies that the musicians are learning each others musical style in the process, building their relationship (*musically speaking*) with one another. *Jamming* will probably include *improvisation* but *jamming* is not *improvisation*.

Also note that because of slang usage of the (*slang*) term, *jamming* can also refer to a musician on their own for example "*he has been jamming in his room all day*". This would refer to the musician *jamming* (*building the relationship*) with his music or instrument rather than other musicians.

To summarize the confusion in detail:

*Jamming* **usually** consists of some *improvisation* where the music is made up spontaneously as it is played. The opposite could be a **rehersal** and thought of as "*practicing*" where a specific piece or song is played through by everyone.

*Improvisation* can be referred to as *jamming* when talking about the growing bond between the musician and music (*here music refers to a song, musical theme, other musicians, or instrument*) or where the music sounds unprepared.

Everyone *jamming* could be *improvising* at some point but they could also be *practicing* a set piece with no *improvisation*.

You improvise, you make it up.

You jam, you gel with external sources of music.

both imply the inclusion of some kind of unpreparednesses.

It's not vague at all, it's clear as mud.

Edit: to attempt to answer your questions

> Some say that improvisation is one player making up melodies over established chord sequences

I've played for years in bands and we all improvised at the same time, every time we got together, to see what ideas come up for new material. I think they're just saying that's one way to improvise, if that's their final and complete definition of improvisation then I'd suggest they get out of the house a little more.

> jamming is starting from basically nothing, and each player adding their own part to the ensuing jigsaw.

that's the standard jazz configuration, the group holds a scene and they take turns trying to pull everyone off course. the idea is that a jazz band should put faith in whoever is improvising, faith that they will bring it all back together somehow before the next persons turn.

> defined differences?
> similarities

yes, think i covered that earlier

edit: the only percieved similarities are when we're talking about a session where that "session" could be called both an improvisation and a jam. It can also be said that the musicians in a session are jamming and/or improvising.

> could one finish playing in an ensemble situation, and say 'that was a good improv', or 'that was a good jam' with any exactitude?

probably, if any of it was improvised then it could be called a good improv.
jam could always be used because even a performance is a way to gel with the group.

> would it be fair to say one (or both) are applicable to any particular genres? or definitely not, as the case may be?

not a chance. it is used everywhere

> it's really confined to jazz

no, not confined at all, it just originated from jazz. as did the term gig which was derived from engagement meaning engaging with an audience. I've been to a few metal gigs, sure you could argue there's always at least some influence that jazz has on metal but... you get my drift

> Dictionary definitions are also mixed and vague on the issue.

They're pretty spot on, it's where the definitions use the other term that's confusing maybe. Example the term jamming will have the word improvisation in its definition and vice versa.

Comment: It's certainly possible to prepare for an improvisation and/or have a plan.

Comment: @PiedPiper for sure, even hooks/melodies, anything from documented records to ideas for how it should feel or what we're aiming for. there's no real limit as to what can be defined and the actual improvisation can be as small as a few notes.

Comment: @PiedPiper those were direct from the dictionary and wikipedia, i think it's still somewhat correct even though we certainly disagree. it can be prepared and planned but i think they narrow it down to the act, as in the performance where the improvisation occurred is "improvised". it means more than that to me though, improvisation almost always has some external influence. I think the subject when concerned with music should include those things.

Comment: I'm having a hard time putting my thoughts down onto the page :S. lemmy know if any needs clarification or better wordsing

Comment: The second line defining improvisation has some problems. Performance without preparation can also be a description of sight reading. Also, a lot of improvisation is based on well worn and practiced patterns.

Comment: "jamming is not improvisation" this seem flat out wrong. If a band was jamming, and later someone asked "what were you playing?" or "where can I get that music?" the musicians would likely say something like "I was improvising that music."

Comment: see how you said "likely"... that means that there is an alternative and they aren't the same @MichaelCurtis you can have a jam where songs are practiced without improvisation

Comment: jamming "can" and most likely does "include" improvisation. if jamming "was" improvisation then you could only say you were jamming if "everyone" was "improvising" the "whole time"

Comment: while jamming can imply improvisation, it is not explicit

Comment: A band practicing songs: rehearsal.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis for sure, it can also be a jam. An outsider would call it a jam if the band wasn't paticularly good. It's always a jam to me because I would never play well enough to call it a rehersal :D and i'd get bored just running through songs, there's always some improvisation and a warm up

Comment: thanks i'm editing with your notes

Comment: Can't we just admit that neither term has a strict definition?  @Tim, I'm ashamed of you for accepting that over-long, rambling, often self-contradictory answer!

Comment: @Laurence - don't be ashamed! It is a genuine question, perhaps one, like I try to ask, that will invoke some thoughtful answers. There probably would be a difference, but maybe it's a cultural or regional thing. Just interested in how others regard the two terms. Myself - still not sure, not even after reading your answer...We won't fall out over it, though, I hope?

Comment: @Tim my shame was that you accepted such a poor quality answer!  But I'm glad to see your new fondness for open-ended 'opinion' questions.  Lots of musical topics are like that, and the group rules stifle a lot of interesting exploration.  (But sorry, yarns, that wasn't interesting exploration, just incoherent waffle!)

Comment: what, there's just so many angles, it makes sense to me in two short sentences but everyone has their angle which i try to address. both terms do have definitions however jamming is slang and also Jamaican for party or having a good time, in music it has a similar meaning though entirely different.

Comment: i gave the analogy in the opening paragraph, to give an example of terms that can be substituted for one another, in most contexts, depending on the point of view.

Comment: @Laurence it's only opinion where the definitions aren't taken into consideration. it's your opinion that the definitions are wrong?

Comment: consider this: our band gets together for a session, we warm up with a few things off the top of our heads and feed off each other, then play some of our songs which always include some kind of improvisation. Then we play a cover song which has no improvisation. We then work on new parts of songs, trying to come up with material. Finally we finish by repeating a passage in our song that we had trouble with recently. if someone asked me what we were doing, I could answer "we were jamming" could I not? This includes the cover song and practicing the bit we had trouble with, which were not improv

Comment: @yarns To your last point, when you practice even in the strictest sense, there are elements of improv. Changing keys for a vocalist? Need to shift what you are playing. Song fades out now? Figure out an ending together. Don't have the same instruments on the track? Cover and omit parts. Even just picking what parts to practice and how to go about it is not a set thing and is improvised. I'm being a bit pedantic, but I do feel with how broad you are using the term jamming, I could literally do the same and say almost every aspect of performing is improv.

Answer (score 7):

It would be pointless to cite Wikipedia, so I'll write this from the top of my head.

Musical improvisation means creating some aspects of music, whatever that is - chords, melodies, rhythms, lyrics, mixes or modular synth routings - on the spot, so that the content hasn't been pre-planned, but you make choices as you go along. The act of improvising can be pre-planned or scheduled, but the exact outcome is not. Choices are made on the spot. Any dimension of music can be improvised. If a DJ is not following a pre-written playlist, the song selection is improvised.

The concept of *jamming* in music has more of a social perspective to it. Jamming is spending time concentrating on what feels good, without pressure and expectations to deliver a very specific, known performance with a specific known length. Usually it means that some improvising goes on, but a drummer can contribute to jamming by playing a steady 4/4 beat without really improvising a note. I think the two main points of jamming are: (1) trying to make oneself and others *feel good*, (2) without a lot of *pressure and expectations* on particularly how *long* it may and has to take.

If you say it was a good jam, it means that the participants succeeded in making you feel good.

Improvisation can be done with tight constraints. For example, a player may be told to play something, anything, to fill a ten-second period of time with musical sound. It has to be *improvised*, but I would not call that *jamming*. Or when a session player (a thing of the past) was given a chord chart, they had to improvise their parts, but it wasn't *jamming*.

Comment: An insightful look at the differences, thank you. Looking forward to some other views from other experienced musos! +1

Comment: but the produced content was pre-planned to be improvised :S

Comment: @yarns Yes, you understood me correctly.

Comment: I agree. The important point is the _final product_ is something new, created on the stop. That final product may be made of elements that are preplanned, practiced, preexisting templates, etc. incomplete or abstract as separate parts.

Comment: don't you think the word "jam" is more closely related to gel with one another than to feel good? the other slang usage of jam is a sticky situation like "you're in a jam". I'd say jam is more related to glue :shrug:

Comment: "Musical improvisation means creating content, whatever that is - chords, melodies, rhythms, lyrics, mixes or modular synth routings - on the spot,"
No it doesn't.   It can just as well cover 'taking a solo' within a strictly defined musical structure.

Comment: @Laurence I don't know how it's possible to understand that in a way that "taking a solo" isn't included. But apparently it is possible.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica your wording is just a little off, 'producing content' sounds like your writing a script, whereas i think you mean to say something closer to 'playing music'. improvisation doesn't produce artifacts, just noise

Comment: @yarns Ok, it was the word "content". I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Improvisation could be defined many ways, and I don't think the point of this question is to find some kind of complete, authoritative definition. Improvisation means some elements of music are not composed out and will be determined on the spot in performance. Usually there is some kind of template, an abstract structure or pattern, guiding the choices of the improviser. Lots of musical elements can be improvised: drum fills in rock music, melodic embellishments in classical style, melodies over chord progressions in jazz, etc. etc. In this sense improvisation is a broad term about making musical choices spontaneously. Lots of styles and lots of techniques can fall under the category of improvisation.

Jamming is much more specifically about improvisation in pop/rock/jazz styles and I think strongly implies improvising with a group of people. A *band* of musicians is what usually comes to mind. Some groups are even called *jam bands*, because they do a lot of extended improvisations in pop/rock/jazz styles.

If you think of something like a Baroque violin sonata, the keyboardist will *improvise* a harmonic *accompaniment* above a composed bass, while the violinist play the melody with *improvised* embellishments. Those two musicians are improvising elements of their performance, but you would not normally describe them as "jamming." That would be an anachronistic use of the term "jam."

On the other hand, if that Baroque duo started to play the same violin sonata with a swing feel, maybe syncopated some notes, added some blue notes, etc. you might say they were "jamming," because you have the improvisation elements, and more importantly the jazz band associations.

Comment: our answers were ultimately the same in length, I just found it was necessary to add the "summary in detail" section to address the many points of view (which for the most part aren't wrong). you state the most common use of the term but not what it actually means which leaves it only useful in certain situations.. the question is asking for clarity, not one aspect of the terms used in a contained context.

Answer (score -1):

> I've been discussing with musos what similarities and differences
> there are between improvising and jamming. There seems to be a lot of
> vagueness here.
>
> ...are there actually defined differences?

No.  And we should have the confidence and academic integrity to say so.  We could discuss it for weeks and come to a consensus on what the difference MIGHT be, or OUGHT to be, but that's not really any use to anyone.

Comment: Sounds more like an opinion than anything else. Could you expand on a terse answer please?

Comment: @Tim Why?  Terse is good. Say what you've got to say, then stop.  We see far too much waffle in answers here already! But ok, I'll pad it out a bit...

Comment: @Tim and Laurence too.  After reading the other answers I can clearly see a consensus as to the distinct **core idea** of each, to which the other elements are optional: for jamming it's the *social aspect* (bonding), for improvisation it's the *musical aspect* (free flow within some boundary while revolving over some structure, sometimes with finality like a concerto cadenza or a chorale prelude).  *What* a session is called depends on *which aspect is primary* although both are present.  Success is measured by the core aspect.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes it's helpful to get some insights by not being quite serious. So when rock musicians collectively improvise they jam. When jazz musicians do the same they might not jam, they might just play, as collective improvisation is all they do anyway. They might jam if they play at the jam session though, but they would never call it jamming - they simply attend the jam session. Jam bands - they don't really jam - they play songs with extended improvised sections. They might be jamming though if they have guests onstage. Jamming indicates social situation. Unless you're jamming to the backing track. Then you might be trying to gel into a preexisting social situation if the backing track was recorded by humans. If it wasn't then you might be still imagining you are playing with bandmates so conceptualy still a jam.

When jazz musician say they do improv that has special meaning, as they anyway always improvise. They just want to say they play free jazz but don't want to use that worn out term.

When rock musicans say they improvise, it typically is not related to the music, but gear or gig logistics.